# mysql results truncated here, but not there

Tags: php, mysql

My first post here.  I have a mysql table,
 - InnoDB
 - latin1-bin
There are about 300 rows/9 columns.  This is a choral library, so most of the columns are varchar, except for an auto-incremented key index column.  Much like a book collection; title, author, composer, etc.

There are two types of views, list view and record view in the CMS.  They are much like typical list and record views in a desktop app such as Lotus Approach or MS Access.

The list view is build on a table with headers (th), rows(tr) and data (td).  30 results per page.  The record views are built on text inputs, where data can be modified, records created/deleted, or searched, and display only one record at a time.

The problem is that on the list views titles that contain subtitles (double quoted strings) are not truncated, and the data is displayed perfectly, (Santus and Bendictus from "St. Cecilia Mass").

```
echo "<td class='whiteData'>$row[TITLE]</td>";
```

However, the same code in a text input doesn't work:
Allowing for escaping characters, changing the code to:

```
echo "<input type='text' name='title' id='title' value= \"$row[TITLE]\" style='width:390px; margin-right:150px; maxlength:75; margin-top:15px' />";
```

Yields "Santus and Benedictus from".  Bear in mind, the first code snippet was from an index view, and the second is from the browse/edit view.  I've tried other combinations such as:

```
...'$row[TITLE]'  or  $row["TITLE"]  or  $row['TITLE']
```

Either of the last two statements throw a php error and just kill the page.  The escape character with double quotes yields everything up to the double quotes. Enclosing the expression in single quotes corrects the problem, but then creates another problem with the title, "God's Wondrous Love" where it is truncated at the apostrophe.  Again, the problem only exists on the record views, (text inputs) and not on the table (list view).

My question: why the difference in behavior?  The data is not getting truncated by the query.  I know that I can simply instruct the users to not use double-quoted strings, and that seems to solve the problem.  But I just thought it curious.

Hope I haven't missed something.  First post wouldn't allow me to post images, so I hope nothing is out of context.

Thanks.

Comment: Consider adding more code (of the view functions/files and of the controller) . Maybe the controll doesn't pass this data or it does pass it with a variable which not named $row.

Comment: just tried a plain old echo, not to an input and that worked ok, but it was still truncated in the text input.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why is that happening, but you could always use regex to parse the value and escape any conspicuous characters in your view.

Comment: ok added this: $temp=$row[TITLE];  $temp = preg_replace('#["]#', "'", $temp); and finally, echo "<input type='text' name='title' id='title' value = \"$temp\" />";  That works.  Don't see any formatting rules here.  Hope I got it right.

Answer (score 0):

When you are inserting the values in an  box, the problem is that the quotes for the 'value' attribute conflict with the quotes in the value itself. This conflict causes the value to be truncated.

Below is an example of how the outputted  will look like assuming $row['title'] contains (Santus and Bendictus from "St. Cecilia Mass"):

```
<input type='text' name='title' id='title' value="Santus and Bendictus from "St. Cecilia Mass"" style='width:390px; margin-right:150px; maxlength:75; margin-top:15px' />
```

So what is happening here is that the first quote in the value is taken as the closing quote for the 'value' attribute. Therefore what the text-box only shows is (Santus and Bendictus from)

I think what you need is the call to htmlentities(). Like this:

-- values enclosed in single-quote

```
echo "<input type='text' name='title' id='title' value='" . htmlentities($row[TITLE]) . "' style='width:390px; margin-right:150px; maxlength:75; margin-top:15px' />";
```

or

-- values enclosed in double-quotes

```
echo "<input type='text' name='title' id='title' value=\"" . htmlentities($row[TITLE]) . "\" style='width:390px; margin-right:150px; maxlength:75; margin-top:15px' />";
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: Abhay, thanks.  No 2 works.  I had tried something similar to your first suggestion, but with my second example, "God's Wondrous Love", it throws the page out of whack.  Labels and inputs are scattered helter skelter, and the value is still truncated.  Your second suggestion works: the page is not scattered, and the results are not truncated with either sample.  Even picks up the double quotes, rather than having to tweak it with preg_replace.

Comment: Great that it works @jazcam. Even my first suggestion should work for values like "God's Wondrous Love" unless the single-quote isn't actually the single-quote

Comment: Tried to reply but the page went dead.  The scattering was that I missed the space after the second concat operator, `. "' style=...` between the single quote and "space".  The outerhtml is getting whacked.

Comment: Sorry, yes I kept getting cut off.  Isp or something.